# Div Fixed to Top but Still Scrollable Horizontally

Tags: html, css, fixed

I want to fix a webpage's header to the top, such as by using position:fixed; in CSS, but if the browser is made smaller than the header's 1000px width I want it to be made scrollable horizontally along with the rest of the page.

Of course I could do this using javascript to change the div's top value in conjunction with absolute positioning, but my preference is for the feature to be accessible to people without javascript as well.  Thanks!

Comment: Scrollable horizontally?  Do you mean vertically?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, no can do. You could also keep it fixed and scroll it horizontally, like so:

```
$(window).scroll(function(){
    var leftScroll = $(document).scrollLeft();
    $('.fixedElement').css({'margin-left':-leftScroll});
});
```

Answer (score 0):

It will scroll horizontally by default, but I think you may mean scroll vertically with the content.

You can achieve this with CSS Media Queries.

```
@media all and (max-width: 1000px) {
    #header {
        position: static;
    }
}
```

http://jsbin.com/UGasor/1

Answer (score 0):

Header is fixed to the top of the page and scrolls horizontally on small sizes (here, sizes less than 600px wide)

```
header{
    position:fixed;
    top:0px;
    width:100%;
    overflow-x:auto;
}
div{
    width:100%;
    min-width:600px;
}

<header>
    <div> [ content ] </div>
</header>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/daCrosby/USMgD/